# PC freezes while training a cnn on cifar 10 dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using tensorflow to train on cifar-10 dataset. My PC freezes when I run the training loop.

```
# forward propagation

# convolution layer 1
c1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_train, w1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
# activation function for c1: relu
r1 = tf.nn.relu(c1)
# maxpooling
p1 = tf.nn.max_pool(r1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
print('p1 shape: ',p1.shape)

# convolution layer 2
c2 = tf.nn.conv2d(p1, w2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
# activation function for c2: relu
r2 = tf.nn.relu(c2)
# maxpooling
p2 = tf.nn.max_pool(r2, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')
print('p2 shape: ',p2.shape)

# fully connected layer
l1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(p2)
# fully connected layer
final = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(l1, 10, activation_fn = None)
print('output layer shape: ',final.shape)
```

I am using softmax cross entropy and adam optimizer:

```
# training and optimization

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = final, labels = y_train))
# using adam optimizer 
optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

This is where it freezes:

```
# creating tensorflow session
se = tf.Session()

# initializing variables
se.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# training the graph
for i in range(1000):
    x_batch, y_batch = mini_batch(x_train, y_train, 110)
    se.run(optimize, {x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
cost = se.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print(cost)
```

Comment: Would be good if you add what PC freezes means here. Did you check the CPU utilization? Were you able to work with other programs while the model was being trained?

Comment: I can't move the cursor, i have to remove my laptop's power supply to shut it down.

Comment: when this happens you usually run out of RAM in a very short amount of time. Try to look at RAM usage while starting your program. Also, you can enable [Magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) and when it freezes hit `Ctrl+SysRq+f` which will kill the process consuming the most memory. (you have to enable it first!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would have been great, if you would have also mentioned your PC configuration. Nevertheless, the programme you are running is not a computationally hard one or one which contains infinite loop, so in my opinion, the problem might arise from your PC, where you may be running a lot of applications, because of which your python daemon is not able to do sufficient allocation, hence the freezing/hanging problem occurs, it not necessarily a code related issue, given this code runs well and fine on my MacBook Pro 2012.

Comment: Core i3 4010u (1.7 ghz), 4gb ram, 500 gb hdd, amd gpu

Comment: Well, Can you please state your GPU? Is it from Nvidia or AMD? Usually, Tensorflow tries to find a GPU and runs on that but it is only supported for CUDA-complaint GPUs, which as of now is just Nvidia GPUs.